# Saving state of gallery images from URL?

Tags: android

Ive i have two images from a URL into my gallery view. But when i go to another activity the images are reloaded again from online. I would like to request this once per application instance. How would i go about saving the state of this?

```
    /** Simple Constructor saving the 'parent' context. */
                public ImageAdapter(Context c) { this.myContext = c; }

                /** Returns the amount of images we have defined. */
                public int getCount() { return this.myRemoteImages.length; }

                /* Use the array-Positions as unique IDs */
                public Object getItem(int position) { return position; }
                public long getItemId(int position) { return position; }

                /** Returns a new ImageView to
                * be displayed, depending on
                * the position passed. */
                public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                ImageView i = new ImageView(this.myContext);

                try {
                                /* Open a new URL and get the InputStream to load data from it. */
                                URL aURL = new URL(myRemoteImages[position]);
                                URLConnection conn = aURL.openConnection();
                                conn.connect();
                                InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();  
                                /* Buffered is always good for a performance plus. */
                                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
                                /* Decode url-data to a bitmap. */
                                Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
                                bis.close();
                                is.close();

                                /* Apply the Bitmap to the ImageView that will be returned. */
                                i.setImageBitmap(bm);
                        } catch (IOException e) {

                                Log.e("DEBUGTAG", "Remtoe Image Exception", e);
                        }

                /* Image should be scaled as width/height are set. */
                i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
                /* Set the Width/Height of the ImageView. */
                i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(150, 150));
                return i;
                }

                /** Returns the size (0.0f to 1.0f) of the views
                * depending on the 'offset' to the center. */
                public float getScale(boolean focused, int offset) {
                /* Formula: 1 / (2 ^ offset) */
                return Math.max(0, 1.0f / (float)Math.pow(2, Math.abs(offset)));
                }
                }
            public class ImageAdapter2 extends BaseAdapter {
                /** The parent context */
                private Context myContext;public ImageAdapter2() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
                }
                /** URL-Strings to some remote images. */

                private String[] myRemoteImages = {imageUrl2};






                /** Simple Constructor saving the 'parent' context. */
                public ImageAdapter2(Context c) { this.myContext = c; }

                /** Returns the amount of images we have defined. */
                public int getCount() { return this.myRemoteImages.length; }

                /* Use the array-Positions as unique IDs */
                public Object getItem(int position) { return position; }
                public long getItemId(int position) { return position; }

                /** Returns a new ImageView to
                * be displayed, depending on
                * the position passed. */
                public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                ImageView i = new ImageView(this.myContext);

                try {
                                /* Open a new URL and get the InputStream to load data from it. */
                                URL aURL = new URL(myRemoteImages[position]);
                                URLConnection conn = aURL.openConnection();
                                conn.connect();
                                InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();  
                                /* Buffered is always good for a performance plus. */
                                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
                                /* Decode url-data to a bitmap. */
                                Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
                                bis.close();
                                is.close();

                                /* Apply the Bitmap to the ImageView that will be returned. */
                                i.setImageBitmap(bm);
                        } catch (IOException e) {

                                Log.e("DEBUGTAG", "Remtoe Image Exception", e);
                        }

                /* Image should be scaled as width/height are set. */
                i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
                /* Set the Width/Height of the ImageView. */
                i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(150, 150));
                return i;
                }

                /** Returns the size (0.0f to 1.0f) of the views
                * depending on the 'offset' to the center. */
                public float getScale(boolean focused, int offset) {
                /* Formula: 1 / (2 ^ offset) */
                return Math.max(0, 1.0f / (float)Math.pow(2, Math.abs(offset)));




                }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the images in separate as static or you can put them in HashMap(key is URL,value is image bitmap) for later use or you can do lazy downloading of images or finally you can use Application class(see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html to maintain global state) but it is not good thing to store the images(generally it will create memory problems),make them download every time using lazy loading.

Comment: I seen this example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/android-how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview/3068012#3068012 do i just supplement the imageView for gallery?

Comment: have u implemented Adapter subclass?

Comment: Yeah i posted above the BaseAdapter i am using in my Main activity to load the images from a URL. Maybe i can put ((Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery))
        .setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this)); in a AsyncTask so the it doesnt block up the main UI? and then how could i save the images in cache or whatever once its downloaded?

Comment: You store the image URL and Bitmap in HashMap in getView(),every time check whether the image URL is new or older one( the check will help you to add URLs later,use the HashMap as static way)

Comment: Okay, but can you edit your answer and explain what your saying. I appreciate it.